# Excel 2007 Chart Not Updating When Border Lines Are Programmatically Changed

Tags: vba, excel, charts, lines

I'm pretty sure this is a bug but maybe I am missing something.

So a surface chart (with all the lines visible) is what I want:

(*ed: ok i tried to post an image but this thing is not letting me post cause its a new account.. but you get the idea*)

And to do that I create my table of data and then *should* run this code:

```
Sub test()
    Charts.Add
    ActiveChart.charttype = xlSurface
    test2
End Sub
Sub test2()
Dim a
    For Each a In ActiveChart.Legend.LegendEntries
        a.LegendKey.Format.Line.Visible = msoTrue
        a.LegendKey.Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
        ActiveChart.Refresh
    Next a
End Sub
```

If I run `test()` though, I get the chart but no lines (which is the excel default).
If I THEN rerun `test2` again, the lines fill up.
Of course, this makes absolutely no sense.

I am by no means a newbie at this (I've helped answer a few questions in my personal account, but am blocked for accessing that at work). I've tried `DoEvents` instead of `ActiveChart.Refresh` as well but no dice. I'm also pretty sure it works properly in excel 2010 (which is where I first tried this out at home) so this seems like a bug in 2007. Bug or no I have to work in 2007 so I'm looking for solutions. Anyone please?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for taking so long to reply but I was trying to get Excel 2007 up on my VM but seems like my VM is giving me troubles so I have not tested this code in Excel 2007 but I believe it should work.

This is the reason why I am always suggesting not to use "Active-Something". Be it `ActiveCell`, `ActiveSheet`, `Activeworkbook` etc. Always declare your variables and then work with the variable(s). You will never go wrong. See this example

```
Sub test()
    Dim objChrt As ChartObject

    Set objChrt = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add _
    (Left:=50, Width:=200, Top:=50, Height:=200)

    With objChrt
        .Chart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:C5")
        .Chart.ChartType = xlSurface
        test2 .Chart
    End With
End Sub

Sub test2(chrt As Chart)
    Dim a
    For Each a In chrt.Legend.LegendEntries
        a.LegendKey.Format.Line.Visible = msoTrue
        a.LegendKey.Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
        chrt.Refresh
    Next a
End Sub
```